# Search everythings using django filter

Tags: django, django-filter

I am trying to search multiple fields and full text Warnings table. I use django filter to search but no returned result. I also refer some code using django filter and follow them but nothing. How do I solve?
Here are some code.

## filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import Warnings


class WarningFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    detail = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    type = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    website = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Warnings
        fields = ['title', 'detail', 'type', 'website']
```

## views.py

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        result = WarningFilter(query, queryset=Warnings.objects.all())
    context = {'filters': result.qs}
    return render(request, 'pages/history_warning.html', context)
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid


class Website(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uri = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Warnings(models.Model):

    TYPE_WARNINGS = (
        ('security', "Cảnh báo bảo mật"),
        ('service', "Cảnh báo dịch vụ")
    )
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    detail = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_WARNINGS, blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can do it like this using [**`filter.method`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method):

```
class WarningFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    q = django_filters.CharFilter(method='filter_q')

    def filter_q(self, qs, name, value):
        return qs.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=value) | Q(detail__icontains=value) | Q(type__icontains=value) | Q(website__name__icontains=value)
        )
```

Usage:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    result = WarningFilter(request.GET, queryset=Warnings.objects.all())
    context = {'filters': result.qs}
    return render(request, 'pages/history_warning.html', context)
```

Comment: I tried in Python console, the returned result is incorrect, I think problem is in filters.py